defining table name in sequelize
After the next model is translated to my database a table called  r_hasStatuses is created. Yet, for this case I want the table to be created to be named as r_hasStatus. I know there is a Models parameter:
https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/models/naming-strategies/
but I do not understand how to use it in my definition:
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {  
    const r_hasStatus = sequelize.define("r_hasStatus",
                        {   comment :   {type: Sequelize.STRING,
                                         allowNull: true,
                                         field: 'comment'
                                        },    
                        }); 

                      r_hasStatus.associate = function (models) 
                        {                                           

                        };  
        return r_hasStatus;
    };

Any suggestions?

Using
https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/
and using freezeTableName and models at the same time I placed the next object as the options for sequelize.define i.e. at its third parameter.
           {
               sequelize,
               freezeTableName: true,
               models: 'r_hasStatus',
                            
           }

